# Add kernel configuration options using configuration fragments in custom YOCTO layer

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, xilinx, bitbake, zynq

I am currently trying to modify the kernel configuration (overwrite default xilinx-linux layer configs) by adding configuration fragments to my custom layer like this :

.bbappend file:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}"
SRC_URI =+ "file://fragments.cfg"
```

fragments.cfg:

```
CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE = y
```

Then I run "bitbake \my-image\" and it parses the fragment perfectly, but it doesn't look like it ends up in the final config.

mismatch-all.txt:

```
Config: CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE
From: <path-to>/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/zedboard-zynq7/kernel-source/.kernel-meta/configs/fragments.cfg
Requested value:  CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE = y
Actual value:     # CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE is not set
```

How to tell bitbake to use my config parameters over the default ones?
Actually, there are a lot of parameters in the "mismatch-all" from different config files scattered all across "kernel-source" directory. What is the priority?

Comment: Did you read manual [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#creating-config-fragments) and [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#adding-recipe-space-kernel-features)? Maybe try to ask in [xilinx mailing-list](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/listinfo/meta-xilinx)?

Comment: Which Yocto version do you use?

Comment: I'm using version 2.3 (Pyro). I read these parts. SCC files don't work at all. Bitbake refuses to generate configuration queue and says "could not find kconf".

Comment: Oh.. I forgot that hardware/non-hardware part. It parses the scc file now, but displays warning during compilation: "specified values did not make it into the kernel's final configuration: CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE". Same thing, but with a proper warning now.

Comment: maybe CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE depends on other settings and it fails to apply due to missing prerequisites? (I never tried fragments configured kernel for now)

Comment: Did you also try to only bitbake virtual/kernel instead of full image, did you also tried to `bitbake -c clean virtual/kernel` before doing it again?

Comment: Yep, I tried virtual/kernel and clean. I am not sure about the dependencies, but the full text of the warning is "specified values did not make it into the kernel's final configuration:

---------- CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE -----------------
Config: CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE
From:<path>/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/zedboard-zynq7/kernel-source/.kernel-meta/configs/fragments.cfg
Requested value:  CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE = y
Actual value:     # CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE is not set

Config 'I2C_SLAVE' has the following conditionals: 
  (none)
Dependency values are: "

Comment: You can try to ask this question on irc [#yocto](https://webchat.freenode.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After updating layers to the latest versions, I discovered "cfg/fragment_errors.txt" file with lines like "Ignoring "CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE = y" -- spaces around equals are invalid". After removing spaces it worked like a charm.